# About the update of SQLite in Android

Tags: android

About the update of SQLite in Android.When you change the structure of the datebase,how can we update the datebase without delete the data?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)

Answer (score 3):

You should override the [onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) Method in the SQLiteOpenHelper. You should code something like this.

```
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
  String update = ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD COLUMN <column_name> <column_type>;
  db.execSQL(update);
}
```

Dropping a table, adding a row, inserting/updating/deleting data should be done here.

[Alter](http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#alter-table-stmt) Table gives you very limited options in performing an update to the database tables. If you want to copy your data into a completely new structure, you should think about creating temporary tables where you can copy data, create the new schema and then copy your data from the temporary tables to the new table, in this upgrade method.

Make sure you have your DB Version numbers correctly updated while creating the DBHelper.

Comment: Thanks.With your help,I have solved this problem by overriding the onCreate Method and onUpgrade Method.

Comment: Don't forget that the database version integer needs to be incremented in order for onUpgrade() to detect the changes.